# How do I add to sudoers.d from a custom rpm

Tags: centos, rpm, packages, sudoers, rpmbuild

I have a custom RPM I created that needs to add entries to sudoers so I have entries added a file in my RPM `/etc/sudoers.d/mypackage` and put my sudo commands in there.

The files gets added and the RPM is generated. Unfortunately, when I try to install the package, it complains:

```
file /etc/sudoers.d from install of mypackage-1.0.0-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from sudo-1.8.6p7016.el7.x86_64
```

The rpm will install fine if I install it with --force such as:

```
rpm -Uvh --force mypackage.rpm
```

I probably could echo the contents of the sudoers file into `/etc/sudoers.d` but I would prefer the sudoers file be tracked with the rpm.

How do I add entries to sudoers from a custom RPM without sudo complaining?

EDIT: To clarify my post a bit, I have a dozen directories filled with files:

```
/etc/sudoers.d
/etc/httpd/conf.d/
/etc/systemd/system
/etc/cron.d
...
```

Because I don't have beforehand the list of directories and this list may change, I tried to do is:

```
%files
/etc/*
%exclude /etc/sudoers.d
/etc/sudoers.d/*
```

but at that point, files in sudoers.d don't get included. If I wanted to mention directories, one by one, I would have to dynamically generate that list of directories

As was suggested, I tried to do `rpm -qf /etc/sudoers.d` and it does say `sudo-1.8.5.el7_2.x86_64` . If I do `rpm -qf /etc/systemd/system`, it does say `systemd-219-19.el7_2.x86_64` but rpm does not complain when I try to install the rpm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because in the `%files` section you have something like this:

```
%files
/etc/sudoers.d/
```

This makes your package not only include the files in `/etc/sudoers.d`; but also the directory itself. You can check this using `rpm -qlp <generated-rpm>`.

`rpm` does not allow different packages to provide the same file or directory. The solution is to only package the files **inside** this directory:

```
%files
/etc/sudoers.d/*
```

Comment: I actually had /etc/* and I voted you up but because if I do that my problem does disappear. However, my problem is I potentially have a varying number of directories in /etc and that is why I did /etc/* . I tried to add an exclude /etc/sudoers.d then add a directive /etc/sudoers.d/* but the files in there ended up not included. Is there a way to include all etc subdirectories without listing them one by one and still work?

Comment: The interesting part is it only does that with /etc/sudoers.d . It does not do that with /etc/httpd/conf.d /etc/profile.d /etc/systemd/system etc

Comment: why do you do an "exclude"? You can just specify manually each of your files (/etc/sudoers.d/file1  etc.) ; either the line I proposed: /etc/sudoers.d/*. You can check afterwards what exactly got included in your rpm using `rpm -qlp`.

Comment: It is logical that it doesn't do that with /etc/httpd/conf.d/ etc; that is because nobody seems to provide those directories. You can check who **owns** a certain file or directory using `rpm -qf /path/to/dir/or/file`

Comment: I edited the post to clarify: yes, it is owned by sudo but the same thing applies with `/etc/systemd/system` (provided by systemd) and `/etc/httpd/conf.d` (provided by httpd) but no warning happens there

Comment: I ended up writing a script that generates the list of folders . Not exactly what I was hoping for but I guess it works. Thanks for the help

Comment: Ok that works, but it is simpler if you remove '/etc/*' and add a list of all files your rpm provides. That's the way to go...